# Does John 14:23 involve a "physical" house?

Tags: john, translation-philosophy

John 14:23 in some translation involves "making our home with them" while some translate them as "make our abode with him" from "ποιησόμεθα μονὴν". Which translation is correct and does that phrase really mean a physical dwelling place?

NIV:

> Jesus replied, "Anyone who loves me will obey my teaching. My Father
>   will love them, and we will come to them and make our home with them.

NLT:

> Jesus replied, “All who love me will do what I say. My Father will
>   love them, and we will come and make our home with each of them.

ESV:

> Jesus answered him, “If anyone loves me, he will keep my word, and my
>   Father will love him, and we will come to him and make our home with
>   him.

Other versions that use "make our home" are NKJV, ISV, NET (which uses "take up residence" instead)

The NASB and KJV use the phrase "abode with him" instead and no "house" or "home" or dwelling place involved:

NASB:

> Jesus answered and said to him, "If anyone loves Me, he will keep My
>   word; and My Father will love him, and We will come to him and make
>   Our abode with him.

KJV:

> Jesus answered and said unto him, If a man love me, he will keep my
>   words: and my Father will love him, and we will come unto him, and
>   make our abode with him.

Comment: The word carries the meaning of either 'a staying' or of 'the place stayed in'.  Context is king here.  See John 14:2 where this word (translated Mansions or rooms) and a different word (translated house) are both used.

Comment: @LukeVo Hope you will like to read [Mansions in Heaven?](https://naturalchurch.wordpress.com/2017/02/26/mansions-in-heaven/) and listen to [John 14  – Our Inheritance - Mansions in Heaven?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_i5idYNg-4o&t=1415s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the context of John 14:23 I believe the promise here refers to the indwelling presence of the Triune God in the personality of the believer. "We" is a plural verb which separates the persons within the Godhead. In other words, the disciple becomes the residence of God.

Jesus also says "before" John 14:23 the following at John 14:15, "And I will ask the Father, and He will give you another Helper/Holy Spirit, that He may be with you forever." So those who love Jesus and treasure His Word become temples for His presence.

To back this up Ephesians 3:17 states, "so that Christ may dwell in your hearts through faith; and you being rooted and grounded in love." Also 1 Corinthians 3:16, "Do you not know that you are the temple of God, and that the Spirit of God dwells in you?" In short, I don't see how a physical house applies.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the "Father's house" as well as the "many abodes" are physical but not 
inanimate. In the sense that they're...us. Christ's believers, born anew, 
born from above, born of God, born of the Spirit. Our spirits, souls, and bodies.
Certainly neither is some inanimate Beverly Hills mansion or condo, made of gold
and silver and precious stones, not far from a beach, golf course, or ski slope 
on earth or in the sky.
The Father's house in John is firstly the Son of Man, His only begotten Son, Jesus
Christ, in Jn 2. "He spoke of the temple of His body." In the context of 14, this 
same person is about to "go [to crucifixion] and prepare a place" for His disciples.
And then come again, 45 hours or so, 3 days and nights later, to receive them to 
Himself, so that where He is, in the Father, we also may be. The Father's House thus 
becomes the Body of Christ, the "dwelling place of God in spirit" locally and "all
the building...growing into a holy temple in the Lord" Eph 2:21-22, universally